# CVS: Error Creating branch in cvs

Tags: branch, cvs

i have just started working on cvs and initially I set up the project on CVS server [ it is on linux server]. Now I want to create my first branch and for that i googled and tried the below commands but i am not able to create it .

i checkout my project and which has branch folder in it.

Now cd to branch folder i entered the below command:

```
cvsserver> cvs tag -b branchname_0
```

after pressing enter i got below response:

```
cvs tag: Tagging .
```

and when i do ls -ltr to branch folder i get:

```
........... 4096 Jan 27 12:49 CVS
```

when i checked at the repository , its even not present there also

Could you please help on it.

Comment: Is it 1996?  Why on earth would you start a project using CVS?

Comment: Actually my comaany project is on it. so i am trying to learn it.